# how to set filter for AutocompleteSupportFragment api updated after jan 2019

Tags: android, google-places-api

how to set filter for country for AutocompleteSupportFragment autocomplete edittext place api with

AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setCountry("IN").build();

not working with new release of google api for place location for 
AutocompleteSupportFragment.

xml file

```
fragment
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
```

java file

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
autocompleteFragment.setCountry("IN");
```

textView without intent it is also useful:

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
   @Override public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) { 
   txtVw.setText(place.getName()+" >> "+place.getLatLng()); 
 } 
@Override public void onError(Status status) {
   txtVw.setText(status.toString()); 
  } 
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Refer the docs
>   https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Places Autocomplete implementation can be done using Intent builder or Fragment.

**Fragment:**

```
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setCountry("IN");    //country type
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME)); 
       //to indicate the types of place data that you want to get.
```

**IntentBuilder:**

```
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
                .setCountry("IN")
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```